# Is Intel tbb task scheduling suitable for a DBMS?

Tags: c++, multithreading, tbb

So i came across Intel TBB and asked myself it it is suitable for some kind of DBMS?

So for example i have a task called process query which executes a statement in my system and returns something by a return parameter. 
This would look for example like this:

```
class ProcessQuery : public task {
private:
    int a;
public:
    ProcessQuery(int n, char* result) :a(n){};
    task* execute() {
        //do something and write the result
    }
};
```

To execute this i would for example do this(it is just an example!):

```
    tbb::task_scheduler_init init(tbb::task_scheduler_init::automatic);
//init of the parameter for the tasks
    ProcessQuery &q1 = *new(tbb::task::allocate_root()) ProcessQuery(1, r1);
    ProcessQuery &q2 = *new(tbb::task::allocate_root()) ProcessQuery(2, r2);
    ProcessQuery &q3 = *new(tbb::task::allocate_root()) ProcessQuery(3, r3);

    tbb::task::spawn(q1);
    tbb::task::spawn(q2);
    tbb::task::spawn(q3);
```

Moreover i would need some task which loops and checks if there is a result and send that back to the query client. So there would be a task which is root and has those `ProcessQuery` task as children. Or even the task get the client passed as reference and send the result when hes done.

So is this suitable or is there some better solution which comes more or less out of the box and has high capability? *(Maybe i am even wrong with the taskscheduler of tbb there is even more inside of the lib i know)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me first fix your ancient-styled example. Since `tbb::task` is low-level API and `task_scheduler_init` is optional, so I'd not recommend to start with them. Use high-level API instead, e.g. [`task_group`](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/task_groups.htm):

```
tbb::task_group tg;
int a;

tg.run([=a]{ /*do something and write the result*/ }); a++;
tg.run([=a]{ /*do something and write the result*/ }); a++;
tg.run([=a]{ /*do something and write the result*/ }); a++;
// ...
tg.wait(); // recommended before program termination
```

As for your question, TBB is designed primarily for parallel computing and it has no sufficient support for blocking operations like file I/O and networking. Because these operations will block worker threads in OS and cause underutilization of CPU resources since TBB limits the number of worker threads in order to prevent [oversubscription](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualizeparallel/archive/2009/12/01/oversubscription-a-classic-parallel-performance-problem.aspx).

But TBB is good with asynchronous I/O when the blocking operation is limited to one single thread and TBB workers process the events it produces. There is one minor problem with excessive utilization of master thread when there are no yet incoming events but it can be worked-around or even fixed in TBB scheduler.

A simple high-level approach for such a producer-consumers pattern is to use the [parallel_pipeline](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/algorithms/parallel_pipeline_func.htm):

```
void AsyncIO() {
    parallel_pipeline( /*max_number_of_live_token=*/ 
        4*task_scheduler_init::default_num_threads(),
        make_filter<void, event_t>(
            filter::serial,           // only one thread can get events
            [](flow_control& fc)-> event_t {
                event_t e;
                if( !get_event(e) ) {
                    fc.stop();        // finish pipeline
                    return event_t(); // empty event
                }
                return e;
            }
        ) &
        make_filter<event_t, void>(
            filter::parallel,         // events can be processed in parallel
            [&](event e) {
                process_event(e);
                enqueue_response(e);  // do not block when write/send back
            }
        )
    );
}
```

To summarize, if you can split your operations as blocking and non-blocking and separate all the blocking operations to dedicated thread(s), TBB can help with organizing scalable computing and reducing latency per one request by processing it in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am sure that this is the answer i was looking for. I think if need some "thread blocking" behaviour i could at least manage to write one of my own which takes the task from a queue and send it to the clients for example. The TBB would process the stuff. I think thats the approach you mention.

Comment: One last thing. Do i get that right that this is a Pipeline which has one stage singlethreaded to get events and the rest of the threads would manage to process them? Moreover could the first "stage" be blocking? Since if there are no requests of clients i wouldn't need to do anything here. What would be the Behaviour here?

Comment: @bennx, yes, this is what you describe. The first stage can block but it might cause the spin-idle of master thread issue which I mentioned in my answer. One workaround is to finish pipeline and block outside of TBB

Comment: Does such Pipeline run continus or do i have to create it and call it whenever i get events? So if i take your example would it permanently try to get a new event with `getEvent`? How does the parallelism work if the input is serial? The first stage would be a fast read/pop of a queue and the second a time taking process and this would process the events parallel while the pop is serial? Filling of the queue would do a other thread/main in that case?